# up and down keys in narrow textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ezuzan/2
HTML:

```
<div>
    <textarea>press up and down</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

textarea {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px
}
```

When I focus on the textarea and press up and down, the text moves. How can I prevent it without changing the heights of the div and the textarea?

Comment: Are you want to focus the textarea for edit. If you dont want to focus then disable the textarea

Comment: I don't think you can, reliably, and still show only part of the text.

Comment: Could you please explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @andyb: Because I don't want the user will experience text moving up and down..

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. Why do you have a textarea that is cut off by a container with a height less than the height of the textarea?

Comment: @andyb: Because the full height of one line of text is big for me. Maybe because the font or something. I am looking for a way to narrow the textarea for the user.

Comment: Yes the `font-size` is making the `<textarea>` expand. Reducing this will make one line _fit_ better. Alternatively, if you only want one line, what about using an `<input>` instead?

Comment: @andyb: I don't want one line. One line was the simplest way to reproduce the case. In more than one lines the problem is the same. I don't want to reduce font size since I want that size.

Comment: With multiple lines in a `<textarea>`, do you expect the user to be able to use the up/down to navigate the text? Are you just looking for a solution to fix the jittery text with one line?

Comment: The only thing I could get working was [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/ezuzan/22/edit) using JavaScript (well jQuery). Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678774/how-can-i-hide-a-textarea-scrollbar-without-using-overflowhidden

Answer (score -1):

Add `overflow:hidden` style to your textarea

> textarea {
>       height: 30px;
>       font-size: 30px;
>       overflow: hidden;
>   }

Comment: i thought you didnt want the text to move with up down keys .... thats what it does .

Comment: @adirohan: Right. And on Chrome, with your change, the text moves.

Comment: ok , then i guess there is no reliable way to do it as you said :)